# How to include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper in ruby gem...? To make use of content_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I need to use content_tag in my gem. How to include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper in the gem.

lib/fun_emoji.rb

```
require 'fun_emoji/version'
require 'json'

module FunEmoji
   class Index

     def initialize(list)

       list.each do |key, value|
          content_tag(:span, value)
        end
     end

   end
end
```

Comment: _Do_ you need to use it, though? It doesn't do much, you can build your own.

Comment: You are telling that use span directly, don't use content_tag is it..?

Comment: Pretty much, yes.

Comment: Cool. Will try doing that. But can you please tell me how to include rails action_view in gem using railtie..? I'm curious. I tried but didn't get it.

Comment: I haven't tried, but adding actionview to your gemspec, requiring something like `action_view/helpers` and including that module into your class sounds like it should work.

Comment: okay. cool. Thanks.

Comment: Do you really need a dependency to do `"<span>#{value}</span>"`?

Answer (score 0):

Really simply, just:

```
require 'action_view'
module FunEmoji
  class Index
    include ActionView::Helpers::TagHelper
    # ... initialize method
  end
end
```

However, this will do nothing:

```
list.each do |key, value|
  content_tag(:span, value)
end
```

`content_tag` returns a string, so you need to do something with the result (remember `each` ignores the return value of its block):

```
tags = list.map { |k,v| content_tag :span, v }
```

Comment: Yes. i had tried this Max. But we cannot require 'fun_emoji' locally. It has to be bundle installed in rails.

Comment: @SrinidhiGs: " It has to be bundle installed in rails. " - yes, The usual process of installing gems. Nothing to do with having actionview as a dependency.

Comment: @SrinidhiGs are you saying that the gem doesnt work outside of rails? I think ActionView is part of rails so you need to add it to your gem dependencies ..